# Should I Put Javascript in the Head or Body of an HTML File?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a search engine, and I have the code to redirect http to https when users access my page.
 Except I'm not sure if I should put it in the *head* or *body* section of my page.
Here's what I've got:

```
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
  location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
}
```

Also I would like to know if the code I have actually works if that's OK.

Comment: You should control the protocol redirection at your web server instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` of your document before any other `<script>` tags, so that it will execute before downloading all the resources for the page.

Answer (score 1):

No matter where you put it will work but you would unnecessarily loading too many doms if you put the script tag later and also making the user wait slightly longer best is head.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
  location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **JavaScript** in head or body You can place any number of scripts in
>   an HTML document. Scripts can be placed in the body, or in the
>   head section of an HTML page, or in both. Keeping all code in one
>   place, is always a good habit.

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
  location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
}
</script>
</head>
```